# Sencha define a global array

Tags: extjs

I want to implement multiple delete with extjs(sencha). after selecting multiple check boxes, I have to send a ajax request to back end , delete and update the database.

So I need to add deleted Id's to global array and collect deleted Ids

How can I define a global array with sencha architecture ?

Answer (score 0):

Note that setting globals is referred as dirty practice and may fail for as soon as you use the 'strict mode' in JavaScript. I recommend you to add a custom Property to the `Ext.Ajax` namespace like so

```
Ext.Ajax.customIdArray = [];
```

You can now access it from anywhere without polluting the global namespace.